# PhoneNumberKit returning AG for toll free numbers

Tags: swift, phonenumberkit

I am a new swift developer.  I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1.

I am parsing numbers using Mamelroy's PhoneNumberKit to return the country code.  The parsing works fairly well (though a little slow at first).  However, when given a number (888) or (866), toll free numbers in the US, PhoneNumberKit returns AG which is the two-digit country code for Antigua and Barbuda.  The NPA prefix for AG is 268, which is not even close to 888 or 866.

I am prepared to handle a result of AG and test to see if it really is an Antigua or Barbuda number, but I'd like to confirm this is a problem with PhoneNumberKit and not something I'm doing wrong.  My code is below.

```
class ContactService {

static let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

static func getFlag(number:String) -> String {

    // Strip out all characters but +
    let basicNumber = number.filter("01234567890+".contains)

    // Get the country code and return it
    do {
        let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse(basicNumber)
        let regionCode = phoneNumberKit.getRegionCode(of: phoneNumber)

        return regionCode!

    }
    catch {

        return "PhoneNumberKit was unable to get the region code."
    }
}
}
```

Three numbers that are returning AG in my contacts are the following:

1 (866) 814-9582, 
(866) 255-9679 and 
(888) 888-7020

Please let me know if this is a known issue or if there is another fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer here (though I had searched GitHub previously): https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit/issues/135.  It says that AG (a US protectorate) is the first country that matches with toll free numbers, so PhoneNumberKit returns AG.  It recommends returning the user's locale instead.

I suggest returning US.

I am leaving this question and answer here to assist others searching SO with this unexpected result.